# Get tablename at the start of event trigger in PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql

I am looking for the possibility to capture the name of a table on CREATE TABLE, DROP TABLE and other operations in my postgres database.
I looked into event triggers and they seem to only be able to capture these events on ddl_command_end (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-event-triggers.html#PG-EVENT-TRIGGER-SQL-DROP-FUNCTIONS), which should work for the CREATE case but not all of the others.

So I wanted to ask, if there exists a possibility to either get the data from a dropped table (as I would need it) or get the information before the event happens.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle we have a option to [recover table](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/FLASHBACK-TABLE.html) but in PostgreSQL we do not have that option. Only thing you can do for this kind of situation [enabling archiving and following PITR steps](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/continuous-archiving.html). It could be on other server or on the server that your database running. It depends on significance of the dropped table and the database.